# Almost surely summable product implies almost sure liminf is 0.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I am looking for an almost sure analog to the following deterministic result:

Let $\{\gamma_k\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers with $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_k=\infty$ and $\{u_k\}$ a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k <\infty$. Then we can conclude that $\liminf u_k=0$.

What if instead we had that $\{\gamma_k\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers with $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_k=\infty$ and $u_k$ a sequence of i.i.d. nonnegative random variables such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k<\infty$ almost surely. Can we make a conclusion about the almost sure $\liminf$ of $u_k$?

---

Edit: here is the proof I have attempted after the useful answer of Kavi Rama Murthy.

Since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k<\infty$ a.s. we know that $P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k(\omega)<\infty\right\}\right)=1$. Let $\omega \in \left\{\omega\in\Omega : \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k(\omega)<\infty\right\}$. Then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k(\omega) <\infty$ and by the deterministic version of the theorem we have that $\liminf\limits_k u_k(\omega) = 0$. Thus,

$$\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k(\omega)<\infty\right\}\subset \left\{\omega\in\Omega : \liminf\limits_k u_k(\omega) = 0\right\}$$

and so

$$1\geq P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \liminf\limits_k u_k(\omega) = 0\right\}\right)\geq P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \gamma_ku_k(\omega)<\infty\right\}\right)=1\\
\implies P\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega : \liminf\limits_k u_k(\omega) = 0\right\}\right)=1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to apply the first result to each sample point $\omega$ for which $\sum \gamma_ku_k(\omega) <\infty$. So the conclusion is $\lim \inf u_n=0$ almost surely.

Comment: I've used your help to attempt a proof, if it's not asking too much could you verify if I have done it correctly?

Comment: @TonyS.F. Your proof is fine.

Comment: I had another question that you might be able to answer, how do we know that the set $\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \liminf\limits_k u_k(\omega)=0\right\}$ is measurable? Does it matter?

Comment: @TonyS.F. If each $u_k$ is a random variable then this set is measurable.

Comment: But how do we know that? There is a theorem or lemma that I am missing. I am not doubting that it is indeed measurable but I don't understand why.

Comment: Fro any sequence of measurable functions, their infimum, supremum, liminf, limsup are all measurable. So $g=\lim \inf u_k$ is measurable. $\{\omega: g(\omega)=0\}=g^{-1} \{0\}$ so this set is measurable.